# Calling a controller method after a bound checkbox is updated

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a Visualforce page bound to a custom controller.  The custom controller contains a custom object called **PlanData**.  This object contains a List of custom objects called **PlanDataDetail**, like this:

```
PlanData    
   List<PlanDataDetail>
      property: SiteName
      property: Product
      ...
      property: Selected
```

In the Visualforce page, I have a repeat tag that iterates over the List of **PlanDataDetail** objects contained within the **PlanData** object.  The **Selected** checkbox displayed in the page is bound to the **Selected** field in the **PlanDataDetail** object.  So, when I check/uncheck the checkbox, that change is reflected in the **PlanDataDetail** object.

What I’d like to do is after the **Selected** checkbox is checked, call a method  in the **PlanData** object.  I can modify the `<apex:inputCheckbox>` in the Visualforce page (bound to the Select property) to include an onclick event handler that calls an ActionFunction, which in turn calls the method in the **PlanData** object.  My question is, how do I know what happens first, the update of the bound checkbox property in the **PlanDataDetail** object, or the JavaScript onclick event?

Or is there some way I can ensure that the call the method in the custom object happens after the bound checkbox property is updated?